# system.mutations is not responding after I ran an ALTER sql on a table A. Table A is also stuck. I just want to drop Table A

Tags: clickhouse

I ran an ALTER sql on Table A. Then table A is stuck, system.mutations is not responding. I also wait 3 hours. I tried below actions,

1. restart Clickhouse service, reboot this Clickhouse server machine. reboot my client computer.
2. checked log, and found this, "Current max source part size for mutation is 0 but part size 1513. Will not mutate part all_24_24_0. "
3. The sql I used is like "alter table A update columnA=columnA/(select sum()....) where ...."
4. No other data is inserting. No recoreds in system.merges or system.replication_queue.
5. Table A has around 1000 records

I just want to drop this table A, then I can recreate it with the history records, but table A is not responding. Also system.mutations.

Comment: Which clickhouse-server version do you use?
"Current max source part size for mutation is 0" check
number_of_free_entries_in_pool_to_lower_max_size_of_merge and number_of_free_entries_in_pool_to_execute_mutation
and background_merges_mutations_concurrency_ratio

check disk free space
look to https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/17962 where described the same error

Comment: version 20.8. 

I set parts_to_delay_insert=2400, parts_to_throw_insert=2400. The error log "Current max source part size for mutation is 0" is gone. I also set background_pool_size=512.

number_of_free_entries_in_pool_to_lower_max_size_of_merge =8
number_of_free_entries_in_pool_to_execute_mutation=10
Those 2 is default value. 

Checked github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/17962, seems he/she fixed the mutations by increasing background_pool_size.

now I can see merge is working from system.parts. But tableA and system.muations is still locking

Comment: fixed. tableA and system.mutations is unlocked. 

I found the file containing my ALTER sql and deleted it. /var/lib/clickhouse/data/"my schema name"/tableA/mutations_25.txt